# Electric field inside a conductor using gauss theorem

Tags: electric-fields, gauss-law

The electric field inside a conductor is supposed to be zero, but if we take a hollow conductor and place a charge inside it, isn't an electric field present at point $P$ (through Gauss theorem)? So, when we say the electric field is zero, does it mean that $E$ is zero literally inside the conductor, i.e. the black part?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Inside a conductor" means actually within a conductor, not just enclosed by a conductor. i.e. the point in space you are looking at is occupied by a conductor. In your image, point P is not "inside a conductor", even though it is enclosed within the conducting shell. If it helps, think of it as "the electric field is always zero within a (perfectly) conducting *material*."

So applying the principle correctly, $E$ is $0$ within the black ring itself, but not in the interior of the shell. A charge imbalance will be induced on the inner and outer conductor surfaces so that the field is zero within the conducting material.